# Is there anyway to get dual wielding without the skills for it?

Tags: titan-quest-anniversary-edition

Is there any way to get dual wielding without the skills for it?

A.k.a the "Dual Wield" Warfare Mastery skill, or the "Reckless Offense" Rune Mastery skill.

Because I've got "Reckless Offense" from a Redfist Twin Dart, and I still need Dual Wield to well, Dual Wield. I just tested it by removing all my Dual Wield points.